# Signal generation in Matlab and Simulink

Tags: matlab, import, signals, simulink

There is a structure `Meas`, which has a binary Signal named `B_cal` having time and value as its Parameters with values being a <20583*1 double> Signal. I am using this Signal in simulink through the From Workspace block with `[Meas.(Meas.time),Meas.value]` as the Parameter of the block. Now i Need to generate a new binary Signal which has only the first bit high(i.e. 1) and all other bits low. The Signal should be of the same dimensions as `B_cal` as i Need to put both the signals in an `OR gate`. I tried and created a vector in the Matlab Workspace :

```
Signal = Zeros(20583,1);
Signal(1) = 1;
```

And then I used a FromWorkspace block in Simulink and tried to Import this Signal by using `Signal` as the block Parameter. But it ives an error that the dimensions should be that of a Matrix.
Could someone tell that how to solve the Problem. Or how can i create a new Structure with the same elements but the value Signal should be as needed i.e. 1st bit high and rest low.

Comment: Read this http://ch.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/fromworkspace.html?searchHighlight=fromworkspace, and this http://ch.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/importing-signal-data-in-simulink.html

Comment: When using the matrix format (as opposed to a time series or a structure) then it must have at least 2 columns.  The first column is time while the second (and subsequent) columns are the data.  Based on how you've defined time fro the `Meas` signal, you want something like `[Meas.(Meas.time) Signal]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have a misunderstanding of the variables intended to be read by the FromWorkspace block.

The block expects a time series defining the value at various points in the simulation.

The From Workspace block help should point you in the right direction on this.
[Mathworks Help Documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/fromworkspace.html?refresh=true)

I believe that something like the following would work for you:

```
>> Signal.time=0;
>> Signal.signals.values=zeros(20583,1)
>> Signal.signals.values(1) = 1;
>> Signal.signals.dimensions = [20583,1]
```